# What is NullSafe way to concatenate two Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two **streams of integers** guestsTravelWith and guests, which I am concatenating but **throwing error when any one of stream is Null**. Is there a nullsafe way to concatenate two streams? Or using if conditions is my only hope?

```
Stream<Integer> guests = code+some_method();
Stream<Integer> guestsTravelWith = code+some_method();
Stream.concat(guestsTravelWith, guests)
```

Comment: Wich version of Java are you using?

Comment: `Stream.ofNullable(guestsTravelWith).orElse(Stream.empty()).flatMap(Function.identity())`?

Comment: It's a pretty serious design flaw for a method returning Streams to return `null` instead of an empty stream.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Unless you *maybe* want to indicate absence of a result. In which case an `Optional` should be preferred. In any case, its a flaw to try to work with a `Stream` that can be `null`. If `null` is used to indicate absence, it has to be immediatly checked and responded to.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap  Was it worth to reconsider the accepted answer after a year in favor of the other answer where no concatenating/joining _two streams_ takes place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not nice at all, but:

```
Stream.ofNullable(guestsTravelWith).orElse(Stream.empty()).flatMap(Function.identity())
```

Or you know, the "less funner" way:

```
guests == null ? Stream.empty() : guests;
```

You should reconsider the methods that return `null` Stream to begin with, which is a terrible idea.

Comment: The last sentence is very important. Why using streams, when breaking the logic with null?

Comment: Do you think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913438/3651739 one is the right answer?

Comment: *You should reconsider the methods that return null Stream to begin with, which is a terrible idea.* Great point. What would be wrong with returning an empty stream instead?

Comment: @OleV.V. exactly zero, if you ask me.

Comment: Even when you decided to replace the straight-forward ternary operator with a more complicated construct, you have the choice between a straight-forward replacement, `Optional.ofNullable(guestsTravelWith).orElse(Stream.empty())` (or `orElseGet(Stream::empty)`), or a more complicated construct, like `Stream.ofNullable( guestsTravelWith).orElse(Stream.empty()).flatMap(Function.identity())`… By the way, `Stream.ofNullable(…)` is not available in Java 8. When you’re using Java 9 or newer anyway, `Objects.requireNonNullElse(guests, Stream.empty())` would be even better than using `Optional`.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just to filter out `null` streams?

```java
Stream<Integer> s1 = null;
Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(1, 2, null, 4);
    
Stream.of(s1, s2)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Stream<Stream>
      .flatMap(s -> s) // or Function.identity()
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

**Update by Holger's comment**
`Stream.concat` should be replaced with `Stream.of` and null-safe [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`
> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream. *(If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)*

```java
    Stream<Integer> s1 = null;
    Stream<Integer> s2 = Stream.of(1, 2, null, 4);

    Stream.of(s1, s2)
          .flatMap(s -> s) // or Function.identity()
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1
2
null
4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 9 use [Strem.ofNullable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable-T-)

> Returns a sequential Stream containing a single element, if non-null,
> otherwise returns an empty Stream.

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't an _element_ that might be null but a _stream_ that might be null.